Getting a list of supported algorithms via CryptoApi in .NET
I can sing data using CryptoApi in c# like this:
X509Certificate2 certificate = GetCertificate();
CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner(certificate);
cms.ComputeSignature(signer, false);
var sigantureData = cms.Encode();

but can I check before signing, is the crypto provider installed that supports the algorithm in the certificate? Can I somehow get a list of supported algorithms?
